# How can I redirect instruction when Reservation status is accepted? twilio

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-flex, twilio-taskrouter

I am using twilio flex, task router and twilio functions. I want to redirect the live call to the function I've created.

The Scenario is,

1. User calls the twilio number.
2. Agent picks up the call from twilio flex dashboard on computer.
3. When agent ends the call, only agent should disconnected, and call should redirect to the function I've created.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is not something I've done, but the first thing that comes to mind is to over-ride the button that ends the call on the agent side. Rather than having it just end the call, it could call out to a Function that [redirects the caller](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#update-a-call-resource) to your function.

I don't have any more detail than that right now. I recommend you try something like this and ask a new question if you have specific questions about the code.